# A C# collection, which behaves like C++ set or priority_queue?

Tags: c#, collections, set

I have written the Dijkstra's algorithm many times in C++ - I need there set or priotity_queue, both give me possibility to add an element and find the least one (using specified comparator). Now, I've got a problem when trying to write Dijkstra in C# - is there any structure which could be useful for me? I need adding and finding or erasing the least element.

Using Visual Studio '08

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SortedSet` if you use a more recent .NET Framework version.